# How to parse an array of json in scala play framework?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, traversal

I have an array of json objects like this

```json
[
  {
    "events": [
      {
        "type": "message",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "action",
            "value": "withdraw_reward"
          },
          {
            "key": "sender",
            "value": "bob"
          },
          {
            "key": "module",
            "value": "distribution"
          },
          {
            "key": "sender",
            "value": "bob"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "credit",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "recipient",
            "value": "ross"
          },
          {
            "key": "sender",
            "value": "bob"
          },
          {
            "key": "amount",
            "value": "100"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "rewards",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "amount",
            "value": "100"
          },
          {
            "key": "validator",
            "value": "sarah"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "events": [
      {
        "type": "message",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "action",
            "value": "withdraw_reward"
          },
          {
            "key": "sender",
            "value": "bob"
          },
          {
            "key": "module",
            "value": "distribution"
          },
          {
            "key": "sender",
            "value": "bob"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "credit",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "recipient",
            "value": "ross"
          },
          {
            "key": "sender",
            "value": "bob"
          },
          {
            "key": "amount",
            "value": "100"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "rewards",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "amount",
            "value": "200"
          },
          {
            "key": "validator",
            "value": "Ryan"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How to traverse through the types, check if it's `type` equals to `rewards` and then go through the `attributes` and verify if the `validator` equals to `sarah` and fetch the `value` of the key `amount`? Pretty new to scala and play framework. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the JSON as case classes or as `JsArray`?

Comment: Tried the Json.parse(obj) but that didn't work as obj is a string array

Comment: please read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson)

Comment: `Json.parse("[]")` does work. Edit your post with the code you tried, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: What exactly do you want as a result? A list of all amount values from rewards where Sara is the "validator", or the sum of those amounts? Or a list of all the  "reward objects" validated by Sara?

Comment: The reward amount value where Sara is the validator

Comment: Well there could potentially be multiple, as you have an array of event arrays. So it is either a list of amount values or a sum. Or if you are extremely sure that there can always be only one reward which has validated by Sara, then it would be a List with one element, which you could retrieve "directly". So I assume the latter?

Comment: I have edited the answer to probably fit your updated question....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse your JSON into a structure of case classes for easier handling and then extract the wanted field like so:

```
val json = 
"""[
 {"events":[
            {
              "type":"message","attributes":[
                   {"key":"action","value":"withdraw_reward"}, 
                   {"key":"sender","value":"bob"}, 
                   {"key":"module","value":"distribution"}, 
                   {"key":"sender","value":"bob"}
            ]},
           {
             "type":"credit","attributes":[
                  {"key":"recipient","value":"ross"},
                  {"key":"sender","value":"bob"},
                  {"key":"amount","value":"100"}
           ]},
           {
             "type":"rewards","attributes":[
                  {"key":"amount","value":"100"}, 
                  {"key":"validator","value":"sara"}
           ]}
        ]
 },
   {"events":[
            {
              "type":"message","attributes":[
                        {"key":"action","value":"withdraw_reward"}, 
                   {"key":"sender","value":"bob"}, 
                   {"key":"module","value":"distribution"}, 
                   {"key":"sender","value":"bob"}
            ]},
           {
             "type":"credit","attributes":[
                  {"key":"recipient","value":"ross"},
                  {"key":"sender","value":"bob"},
                  {"key":"amount","value":"100"}
           ]},
           {
             "type":"rewards","attributes":[
                  {"key":"amount","value":"200"}, 
                  {"key":"validator","value":"Ryan"}
           ]}
        ]
 }
]
"""
```

```
case class EventWrapper(events: Seq[Event])
case class KeyValue(key: String, value: String)
case class Event(`type`: String, attributes: Seq[KeyValue])
```

```
 import play.api.libs.json._

    implicit val kvReads: Reads[KeyValue] = Json.reads[KeyValue]
    implicit val eventReads: Reads[Event] = Json.reads[Event]
    implicit val eventWrapperReads: Reads[EventWrapper] = Json.reads[EventWrapper]

    val rewardAmountsValidatedBySara = Json
      .parse(json)
      .as[Seq[EventWrapper]]
      .flatMap {
        _.events.collect {
          case Event(t, attributes) if t == "rewards" && attributes.contains(KeyValue("validator", "sara")) =>
            attributes.collect {
              case KeyValue("amount", value) => value
            }
        }.flatten
      }

    val amount = rewardAmountsValidatedBySara.head
```

For your example, `rewardAmountsValidatedBySara` would yield a List of Strings containing only the String `"100"`. Which you could retrieve (potentially unsafe) with `.head` as shown above.

Normally you would not do this, as it could throw an exception on an empty List, so it would be better to use `.headOption` which returns an `Option` which you can then handle safely.

Note that the implicit `Reads` are Macros, which automatically translate into Code, that instructs the Play Json Framework how to read the JsValue into the defined case classes, see [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) for more info.